# node-inspector/chrome instance showing no source files, no call stack, nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

Trying to get node-inspector to actually debug a very simple sample server  app.  I can start the debugger from the command line (`node-inspector simple.js`) just fine and it gives me the standard `Node Inspector v0.8.3
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging` message after starting.

I go to that address in Chrome and the expected debugging interface shows up.  However, there is no data.  Absolutely no data anywhere - nothing in source files, callstack, breakpoints, console.  I hit F8.  It unpauses - still no data anywhere.

I've tried the `--debug-brk` option during startup - same result - no data anywhere in the debugger.

What am I missing?

node-inspector: v0.8.3

nodejs: v0.10.35

chrome (chromium): Version 39.0.2171.65 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17

Here's the code I'm trying to debug (filename is `simple.js`).  It runs fine via `nodejs simple.js`

```
var http = require('http');
function func(arg1, arg2) {
    var result = 'Hello from func. ';
    result += arg1;
    result += ' ';
    result += arg2;
    return result;
}
var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
    debugger;
    var str = 'string',
    num = 10,
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    buffer = new Buffer('x'),
    undef;
    resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    resp.end(func(str, num) + '\n');
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `node-debug simple.js`? `node-inspector` starts a server, but it doesn't take any arguments. It just connects to any node process with debugging enabled. So you can also run `node --debug-brk simple.js` in one terminal and `node-inspector` in another.

Comment: This is the answer.  Somehow I was missing the fact that you had to run two things in order to get the desired result.  Some of the tutorials on setting this kind of thing up seem to be unclear on that.

Comment: One additional item: note that in the debian packaged version of node (v0.10.35) there's an issue that is currently be worked on which prevents node from working correctly with node-inspector. You need to roll node back to v0.10.33 to avoid getting the `Runtime.getProperties failed. ReferenceError: includeSource is not defined` error; see issue #461 at the node-inspector github page for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node-inspector` command runs a standalone server that can connect to an independent node process that has had its debugger enabled (usually by passing `--debug` or `--debug-brk` to node when running the script. It does not run your program for you.

It looks like the `node-inspector` package comes with a `node-debug` command that can be used to both run a script, and open your browser to the debugger at the same time, so that may be more appropriate for what you are looking for.

Comment: Correct - `node-debug` will do some lifting for you, like opening your browser automatically, but be aware that it looks at the default browser setting of the OS.  So if your default browser is not Chrome, it won't work.  I don't see a command line option to indicate which browser to use when launching node-debug; this feature is currently part of a discussion in the node-inspector forums.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the --inspect-brk. That did the magic for me.